# Open .csv file with template from XLSTART

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I'm testing the program which would create a large .csv file and need to open it with minimum clicks (saving my hands) during testing.  The file contains 20+ columns of counters, no formatting required except to suppress zeroes.  I have a template in XLSTART which is used to open new Excel file with no zeroes, but when clicking on .csv file, Excel uses standard template with zeroes.  I know how to suppress zeroes, just do not want to do it every minute.  Importing the file takes even more clicks, so no use.
Appreciate any help!
A

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this. It can load data from a CSV file and transform it as required, leaving the result in an Excel table.  You can set Power Query to Refresh data when opening the file.

Here's a blog post describing this:
http://www.excel2013.info/power-query/automatic-update/

Comment: Thank you!  This is very interesting, I will try it for my more complicated .csv files.  Meanwhile, I changed my program not to add any value to the field when it it zero and it solved the problem for now for now.